# How do I match an argument based on its base class type in rhino mocks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm attempting to stub a method using a type constraint on one of the arguments.  Normally I already know the type and write:

```
o.Stub(x => x.SomeMethod(Arg<bool>.Is.Anything)).Return(...);
```

Instead, I'd like to catch all calls to `SomeMethod` where the first arg passed in derives from a base class, say `B`.  Is this possible?  Can someone help with an example?

Pseudo code for what I'd like to specify:

```
o.Stub(x => x.SomeMethod(Arg.Type.Equals(typeof(B))).Return(...);
```

and have this catch calls like `SomeMethod(a);` where `a` is of type `A` and `A` derives from `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Rhino Mocks does support that as part of its [constraints](https://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#Inlineconstraints), your code should be something like:

```
o.Stub(x => x.SomeMethod(Arg<B>.Is.TypeOf)).Return(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example.

```
o.Stub(x => x.SomeMethod(Arg<B>.Is.Anything)).Return(...);
```

...should work for any classes derived from B.